# MASM Printing Unknown Char

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

So I have a program that takes two user input strings. One to be searched, and one filled with chars to search for. Code for the function is as follows:

```
.data
    string1 DWORD 101 DUP(?),0
    string2 DWORD 11 DUP(?),0
    results DWORD 11 DUP(?),0
    resultsStore DWORD 0,0
    prompt1 BYTE "Enter your first String: ",0
    prompt2 BYTE "Enter the chars to search: ",0
    storeLoop DWORD 0
    storeCount DWORD 0
.code
main PROC
    mov edx, offset prompt1                     ;moves the first prompt into edx
    call writeString                            ;prints the first prompt
    mov edx, offset string1                     ;moves the first response into edx
    mov ecx, 100                                ;sets the limit for the first respsonse
    call ReadString                             ;read user input into the first response
    mov edx, offset prompt2                     ;moves the second prompt into edx
    call writeString                            ;prints the second prompt
    mov edx, offset string2                     ;moves the second response into edx
    mov ecx, 10                                 ;seets the limit for the second response
    call ReadString                             ;read user input into the second response
    call checkMatch
    call crlf
    call WaitMsg
    invoke ExitProcess,0
main ENDP    

checkMatch PROC
        L1:
            mov ebx, storeCount                     ;store the count to access chars in string
            mov storeLoop, ecx                      ;store the count running the outer loop
            mov ah, BYTE ptr [edx+ecx]              ;move individual char to al
            inc ebx                                 ;increment the position in the string
            mov storeCount, ebx                     ;store the string position      
            mov edx, OFFSET string1                 ;move string1 into edx
            mov ebx, 0                          
            L2: 
                mov al, BYTE ptr [edx+ebx]          ;move the next char into al
                cmp ah, al                          ;check if chars match
                je match                            ;if yes, jump to match
                inc ebx                             ;increment ebx
                loop L2
            jmp next
            match:
                mov ebx, resultsStore               ;move next location in string to ebx
                mov results[ebx*4], ecx             ;store char in next open location
                inc resultsStore                    ;increment the location of the next open spot
            next:
                mov ecx, storeLoop                  ;store the outer loop count 
                loop L1
        mov edx, offset results
        call writeString
        ret
        checkMatch ENDP

    END main
```

But when I run the program, it just prints out one of those question mark in a box chars.

Interestingly, if I add the line `call writeString` right after `L1:` the results string prints, followed by string1 multiple times and then the mystery char.

I need to just print the results string, but I'm not sure what in here is causing it to not be printable on its own. My best guess would be some sort of pointer issue, but I'm not positive.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to write in `results` but scaling by 4 looks suspicious. Anyway, use a debugger to single step the code and find out where it does something else than what you intended.

Comment: Apologies, results is supposed to have a char added to it if the current char from string2 is found in string1. As for where it occurs, I'm not great with the debugger, but it looks like when the writeString is missing it doesn't properly store anything in eax from the ah call.

Comment: [MCVE] .. it's not clear from question what is in registers when this code starts, and what is in memory, and what you want as result. Some example? But you probably misunderstand how the "string" is encoded in memory. In the end you put "results" into argument for `writeString`, but `results` is "`int[]`" array, not string (you don't add char, but write some counter, upon match).

Comment: So upon sleeping on it I've unfortunately discovered that what I thought was the correct results was actually just the second string being printed again. That would mean my error lies in the way I am adding my results.